# How can I add recent posts to menu like mashable

Tags: plugin-development, functions, theme-development, query-posts, navigation

I would like create a mega menu that uses recent posts for hover state. Like When you hover a submenu you get a list of recent post relevant to that menu item like in Mashable.
I

I would like a menu walker that will retrieve the menu from the dashboard and assign recent posts to submenu of certain parent menu ID.

[image]

Comment: A large chunk of how to do this is going to be CSS/JS work that's unrelated here and would be out of scope of this site. You might be better off breaking your question apart, e.g how to replace a menu item with a list of posts, remember, you can ask more than one question on this site, so don't ask 1 overarching too broad question when you can ask 5 separate ones

Comment: I have updated my question based on your recommendation. Thanks.